# How to set same dimension for trapezium in a flow chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I have the following code to plot the flow chart:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                positioning,
                shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shapes.geometric}
\begin{figure}[h!] %The block diagram code is probably more verbose than necessary
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.85, transform shape,
    node distance=5mm and 20mm,
% Define block styles
     base/.style = {draw, text width=28mm, minimum height=10mm, align=center},
    baseL/.style = {draw, text width=65mm, minimum height=10mm, align=center},
    baseS/.style = {draw, text width=28mm, minimum height=10mm, align=center},
startstop/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=red!30},
       io/.style = {trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                    base,
                    text width=#1, fill=blue!30},
     io/.default = 7em,
  processL/.style = {baseL, fill=orange!30},
  processS/.style = {baseS, fill=orange!30},
 decision/.style = {diamond, aspect=1.5,
                    base, fill=green!30},
    arrow/.style = {thick,-stealth}
                        ]
\node (start)   [startstop]                 {Start};
\node (LAB1)    [processL, below=of start]  {Implementation of LabVIEW program for acquisition and calibration of IMU measurements};
%-----------------------------------------------------------%
\node (in1) [io, below left=of LAB1]    {Calculate $K_0$, at the idle state of IMU};
\node (in2) [io, below =of LAB1]        {Calculate $\overline{S}$ and $\sigma^{2}$};
\node (in3) [io, below right=of LAB1]   {Calculate $K$};
%-----------------------------------------------------------%
\node (LAB2)    [processS, below=of in2]        {Accuracy analysis};
\node (LAB3)    [processL, below=of LAB2]       {Implementation of LabVIEW program for acquisition of corrected IMU measurements, using $K_0$ and $K$};

\node (testdrive)    [processL, below=of LAB3]          {Conducting test drive and IMU orientations and tachymeter position measurements};
\node (evaluation)    [processL, below=of testdrive]    {Evaluation of recorded data};
\node (comparison)    [processL, below=of evaluation]   {Comparison of IMU measurements with three methods};
\node (stops)   [startstop, below=of comparison]        {Stop};
%-----------------------------------------------------------%
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (LAB1);
%-----------------------------------------------------------%
\draw [arrow] (LAB1) -| (in1);              % to diamonds
\draw [arrow] (LAB1) -- (in2);
\draw [arrow] (LAB1) -| (in3);
%-----------------------------------------------------------%
\draw [arrow] (in2) -- (LAB2);               % from diamonds
\draw [arrow] (in1) |- (LAB3);
\draw [arrow] (in3) |- (LAB3);
%-----------------------------------------------------------%
\draw [arrow] (LAB3) -- (testdrive);
\draw [arrow] (testdrive) -- (evaluation);
\draw [arrow] (evaluation) -- (comparison);
\draw [arrow] (comparison) -- (stops);

\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Flow-chart}}
    \label{figure3111111}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

However, the parallelogram-shaped are in different dimensions, even though I have set a single setting for three(marked in the picture).
Could you help me to make them symmetrical?

Secondly, after the process **Accuracy analysis**, there I would like to have a more space between:

**Accuracy analysis**

and

**Implementation of LabVIEW program for acquisition of IMU measurements, and apply correction using $K_0$ and $K$**

than I have defined. **A vertical distance.**

Since I have a global setting of the flowchart, I couldn't change it. Could you also help me with that?

Comment: your code contain error. your code hasn't diamond shapes. also many definitions and libraries are doubled.

Comment: no, it has spurious `}` after label. please, clarify which distances you like to increase? vertical above/below `io` nodes? distance between `io` nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this?

[image]

i made the following changes in your code:

- slightly reduce distances between `io` nodes.
- redefine `io` node style definition
- remove to my opinion superfluous style definition
- remove doubled loading of the  `tikz` libraries

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                  positioning,
                  shapes.geometric}

  \begin{document}
      \begin{figure}[h!]
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}[
      node distance=5mm and 10mm,
  % Define block styles
       base/.style = {draw, text width=28mm, minimum height=10mm, align=center},
  startstop/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=red!30},
    io/.style args = {#1/#2}{trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
                      trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                      draw, fill=blue!30,
                      minimum width=#1, minimum height=#2,
                      text width =\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
                      align=center},
   processL/.style = {base,text width=65mm, fill=orange!30},
   processS/.style = {base, fill=orange!30},
   decision/.style = {diamond, aspect=1.5,
                      base, fill=green!30},
      arrow/.style = {thick,-stealth}
                          ]
  \node (start)   [startstop]                 {Start};
  \node (LAB1)    [processL, below=of start]  {Implementation of LabVIEW program for acquisition and calibration of IMU measurements};
  %-----------------------------------------------------------%
      \begin{scope}[io/.default = 7em/13mm]
  \node (in1) [io, below left=of LAB1]    {Calculate $K_0$, at the idle state of IMU};
  \node (in2) [io, below =of LAB1]        {Calculate $\overline{S}$ and $\sigma^{2}$};
  \node (in3) [io, below right=of LAB1]   {Calculate $K$};
      \end{scope}
  %-----------------------------------------------------------%
  \node (LAB2)    [processS, below=of in2]        {Accuracy analysis};
  \node (LAB3)    [processL, below=of LAB2]       {Implementation of LabVIEW program for acquisition of corrected IMU measurements, using $K_0$ and $K$};
  \node (testdrive)   [processL, below=of LAB3]   {Conducting test drive and IMU orientations and tachymeter position measurements};
  \node (evaluation)  [processL, below=of testdrive]  {Evaluation of recorded data};
  \node (comparison)  [processL, below=of evaluation] {Comparison of IMU measurements with three methods};
  \node (stops)   [startstop, below=of comparison]    {Stop};
  %-----------------------------------------------------------%
  \draw [arrow]   (start)   edge (LAB1)
                  (LAB1)    edge (in2)
                  (in2)     edge (LAB2)           
                  (LAB3)    edge (testdrive)
                  (testdrive)   edge (evaluation)
                  (evaluation)  edge (comparison)
                  (comparison)  to (stops);
  %-----------------------------------------------------------%
  \draw [arrow] (LAB1) -| (in1);              % around trapecium
  \draw [arrow] (LAB1) -| (in3);
  \draw [arrow] (in1) |- (LAB3);
  \draw [arrow] (in3) |- (LAB3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{Flow-chart}
      \label{figure3111111}
  \end{figure}

  \end{document}
  ```